# C++: Is it safe to change value of iterator of a while loop?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        int x = 10;
        while (x>0) {
                x = x-1;
                cout << x << "\n";
        }
        return 0;

}
```

In this simple program, I change value of iterator of a while loop. But is it safe to do that? Will the program run into segmentation fault sometimes?

How about this pseudo code:

```
vector <vector<Struct> > all_vectors;
vector<Struct> old_vector, new_vector;
Initialize old_vector;
all_vectors.push_back(old_vector);

index = 0;
while (all_vectors[index].size()>0) {
     calculate new_vector;
     if (new_vector not empty) all_vectors.push_back(new_vector);
     index += 1;
}
```

My real code is a bit messy and lengthy so I only posted the main idea of my real code. But for this case, I run into segmentation fault. When I try to debug, the problem seems to be with the line: index += 1.
I cannot understand why. I am sorry if my code is not readable, I am just learning C++.

Comment: Why do you think it could be unsafe?

Comment: This is a normal thing to use a while loop for... totally safe.

Comment: How else would the loop ever stop running?

Comment: Just a note on terminology, an iterator in c++ usually refers to a specific object used to iterate a container or range. An `int` is not an iterator.

Comment: Please see my updated question. Thank you.

Comment: Ask yourself: what happens when `index == all_vectors.size() - 1` and `new_vector` is empty?

Comment: @DeanJohnson then all_vectors[index] does not exist?

Comment: Yes - that is your segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes, and `all_vectors[all_vectors.size()]` makes your program have undefined behavior. Btw, your pseudo code could just as well have been made into real code with just a few changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing now, but if your loop look something like the second example you provide, the segmentation fault could be caused by the check in the while statement.

```cpp
...
index = 0;
while (all_vectors[index].size() > 0) {
                   ^-- This, this could be the problem
     ...
     index += 1;
}
```

The reason being that the program tries to access a vector that is out of range.
This would probably fix the problem

```cpp
...
while (index < all_vectors.size() && all_vectors[index].size() > 0) {
       ^---- Check this index first  ^---- only checked if first condition is true
...
```

And by the look of it, i would recommend using a for loop instead:

```cpp
...
for (size_t index = 0; index < all_vectors.size() && all_vectors[index].size() > 0; ++i) {

...
```

I could also recommend when having segmentation fault with vectors to use [.at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of `operator[]` because that does a range check, and can help you find the problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

You want to ask whether changing the value of the loop variable (x) is safe or not. Remember, an iterator is an object (like a pointer) that points to an element inside the container so the integer variable `int x` is not an iterator.

Now, the answer to your question would be that it is **totally safe** to change the value of the loop variable inside the loop body. You cannot expect the loop to terminate if you are not changing the value of the loop variable!

Coming to the second part, changing the value illogically would result to an infinite loop or a segmentation fault. Suppose, you have written `x=x+1` instead of `x=x-1` inside the loop body, the value of x will always be more than 0 in this case and hence the loop will never terminate.

Answer (score 0):

It is inherently necessary to change the value of an input iterator in order to advance (in typical cases). If you don't change the iterator that is used as the end condition, then you will never reach the end of the interations unless the iteration starts at the end - i.e. there are zero iterations.

Note that iterator is different concept from a loop variable, but the answer applies equally to loop variables as well.